# Updating complex linked tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

How do I solve the following issue:

I want to add a new row to the table *submitted_pictures*, which is linked as follows:

```
game.rb
    has_many :rounds
    has_many :participants, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :submitted_pictures, :through => :rounds
    has_many :users, :through => :participants
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :rounds, :reject_if => :all_blank

round.rb
    belongs_to :game
    has_many :submitted_pictures, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :submitted_pictures

submitted_picture.rb
    has_one :round
    has_one :game, :through => :rounds
    belongs_to :user
```

So I could call:

```
<% @user.games.rounds.last.submitted_pictures.each do |blabla| %><% end>
```

I made a complex form using:

```
<%= form_for(@game) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :round do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.fields_for :submitted_pictures do |fff| %>
            <%= fff.label :flickr_id %>
            <%= fff.text_field :flickr_id %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit Picture", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Hoping to add a new submitted_picture with the flickr_id (which holds a httplink for now), linked to the the current game (@game).

I've been trying several things to update it but it doesnt seem to budge: (the *update_attributes* is totally wrong I see now :p)

```
def update
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    if @game.rounds.last.submitted_pictures.update_attributes(params[:id])
        flash[:success] = "Pic Submitted!"
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

Also

```
def update
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    if @game.save
        flash[:success] = "Pic Submitted!"
        redirect_to games_path
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
```

end

I can't get it to work. I'm getting all kinds of errors, so instead of noting them all here I thought it would be best to ask for the best solution.

So in short, I'm wanting to add a submitted_picture to the latest round (most recent created_at) of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think nesting everything in a game form is making things unnecessarily complicated for you.  If I understand correctly, you want to create a new submitted_picture and it needs to have a game selected.  The round is not directly selected, but is just the latest for the game.  (this sounds like a suspicious assumption--but it does keep things simpler so I'll roll with it)

So just make a new submitted_picture form, and add in a game select.

In your handler, pull the latest round from the game and merge that round into your params to save the new picture.

Does that do what you want?

Comment: thats exactly what I want. I thought making these forms was the best Rails way to do it, but it is indeed very complicated. I'm now looking into it, but still it confuses me a bit wether you are using Update, New, Create or w/e

Comment: I'm already encountering something: im having a Show page for Games, and that view has both a button to start a new round and a button to submit a picture. How do I link those to different actions? It's pretty hard to find this stuff on Google if you dont know what to look for :P